# How to make an effect in HTML like this one https://www.google.com.pk/green/energy/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an effect in HTML/CSS and Javascript like the this one in Google Green website https://www.google.com.pk/green/energy/. When we hover on Using Green Power or Investment Plans a green and red circle comes up. I shall be thankful to him or her who will answer my question.
Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't off-topic, it is a little too "do this for me", but the question is how to replicate the hover effect on that website. It isn't asking for any recommendations. Answer posted below with CSS only, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely work-arounds using pure CSS so that you don't have to use a SVG image, and I've put one together in this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d67hdnmc/).

It is a fairly simple task, you just create the container for your image/text that you want to have the oval hover effect. In my example, I just used a `p` tag to hold everything together.

Inside your container you need a wrapper for your image/text that you want to be displayed at all times (the `span.text` in my example) and the `span.circle` element that holds the oval effect.

Using `border-radius` and `transform` I created the oval base look, and used a few `box-shadow` calls to give the oval the "3D bottom border" look. I used an extra shadow to give it a floating feeling as well.

You arrange the text/image (`span.text`) and the oval (`span.circle`) inside of the container (`.hover`) by making the container and text/image `position:relative;` and the oval `position:absolute;`. To make sure the text/image overlays the oval, you need to give the text/image wrapper a `z-index` larger than the `z-index` of the oval. Lastly, you need to give the oval a `bottom` position to tell it to stick to the bottom of the container. The `padding` on the container allows you to use `bottom: 0px;` and not have the bottom of the oval flushed with the bottom of the text. However, which I'll go into next, you can use negative values for `bottom` which is exactly what I did to give it that "fade in/up" animation on hover.

Now to get the nice animation on hover, all you need to use is the `transition` in CSS. Set the `transition` on the oval (`span.circle`), and make sure you either declare `bottom` and `opacity` as the transitions or the catch-all `all` so that they animate/transition when their value is changed. The `opacity` is default set to `0` so that it is hidden when the element is not being hovered.

The last thing to do is to give the container (`.hover`) the `:hover` pseudo-class so that when you hover the text/image (`span.text`) the oval (`span.circle`) appears and does the nice transition in. I decided to do two different text colors just so it was easier to read both when you hover and are not hovering. All of that is creative liberty, however, and not necessary to create the oval effect.

Below is the code from the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d67hdnmc/).

This should work in all modern browsers. But I didn't test it in anything other than Chrome.

HTML:

```
<p class='hover'>
    <span class='text'>Green Hover!</span>
    <span class='circle green'></span>
</p>
<p class='hover'>
    <span class='text'>Red Hover!</span>
    <span class='circle red'></span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.hover{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
}
.hover:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
}
.hover:hover .circle{
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 5px;
}
.text{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1);
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
.circle.green{
    background: #0d8900; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0d8900 0%, #299a0b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0d8900), color-stop(100%,#299a0b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0d8900 0%,#299a0b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0d8900 0%,#299a0b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0d8900 0%,#299a0b 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #0d8900 0%,#299a0b 100%); /* W3C */
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px #006806, 0px 3px 0px 0px #006806, 0px 2px 0px 0px #006806, 0px 1px 0px 0px #006806, 0px 5px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
}
.circle.red{
    background: #bf0000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bf0000 0%, #cc1e1e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bf0000), color-stop(100%,#cc1e1e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bf0000 0%,#cc1e1e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bf0000 0%,#cc1e1e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bf0000 0%,#cc1e1e 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bf0000 0%,#cc1e1e 100%); /* W3C */
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px #9B0000, 0px 3px 0px 0px #9B0000, 0px 2px 0px 0px #9B0000, 0px 1px 0px 0px #9B0000, 0px 5px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
}
```

Edit: Where I got the [source](http://enjoycss.com/gallery/shapes/dI) for a better looking oval

Answer (score 0):

You need to create image sprite in png.
Then in css use this code.

```
foo{
 background: url("imagefolder/image-sprite.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

foo:hover{
 background-position: -10px 0;
}
```

P.S. For cool transition use something like this.

```
transition: all .3s ease;
```

Comment: I don't think its possible to change the color of an image using CSS.

Comment: If you will using png with transparent alpha changel you can use background color under image.

Comment: I disagree. Could you show an example?

Comment: I mean, yes this works, but almost any CSS styling desire could be accomplished by just making an image/svg of how you want elements to work. The less images you can use by creating it with HTML/CSS the more control you have to tweak/be dynamic.

Comment: Ok. http://jsfiddle.net/hojbzoq9/